# Return multiple value with jquery (post method)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to return 2 values in my post requests.

This is my jquery code:

```
function getPre(value){
    $.post("getform.php", {data : value, cat: null}, function(data){
        $("#tableid").html(data);
        $("#foot").html(MYSECONDVAR);
    });
}
```

Actually, my getform page display multiple html table and I would like to return another value, separate of data.

If i put MYSECONDVAR in parameter of my function

```
function(data, MYSECONDVAR)
```

How can I separate this 2 parts in my getfrom page ?

Is this is possible ? Thanks.

Comment: Make your server code return a JSON object.

Comment: you should return an array from php converted to JSON

Answer (score 1):

Your server should return an object value such as:

```
return data = { attr1: 'value1', attr2: 'value2' }
```

And your function should be like bellow:

```
function getPre(value){
    $.post("getform.php", {data : value, cat: null}, function(data){
        $("#tableid").html(data.attr1);
        $("#foot").html(data.attr2);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return an array consisting of the two values and then access them by index. You could also make another object type that holds these two values, but I think making an array of these two values would be much easier.